# How to read email from outlook account with oauth2 and no user interaction

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, exchange-server, office365api

I working on a console app that must logon to a outlook365 email account and then get the attachments in emails.

I currently have the code I found on [ExchangeOAuth2](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md).

When I get to the part the token has to be retrieved, it opens a website and I have to select an account to be able to continue.

How can I prevent this. There is no user interaction.

My code:

```
 string? host = Configuration.GetSection("email").GetValue<string>("host");
 int? port = Configuration.GetSection("email").GetValue<int>("port");
 string? clientId = Configuration.GetSection("email").GetValue<string>("clientId");
 string? tenantId = Configuration.GetSection("email").GetValue<string>("tenantId");

 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(host) || port == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId) || 
     string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantId))
 {
   return;
 }

 var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
 {
   ClientId = clientId,
   TenantId = tenantId,
   RedirectUri = "http://localhost"
 };

 var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
     .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)
     .Build();

 var scopes = new string[] {
   "email",
   "offline_access",
   "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All" // Only needed for IMAP
 };

 var authToken = await 
 publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

 var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.Username, 
     authToken.AccessToken);
```

[update]
I have changed my code to use microsoft graph.
I used [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?context=outlook%2Fcontext&tabs=aad)

But this is still asking me to go to a website en fill in the code.

That is exactly what I'm not looking for.
There is no user interaction, the console must run on it's own.

Why is this so hard?

Does anyone have an example on how to do this?

Comment: afaik you may store the token (and also a refresh token) after the first interactive session, then re-use the stored token, so that subsequent requests will not require user interaction until the tokens are expired

Comment: I am getting authToken.Account is NULL. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.
In the azure envronment for the email account, some API permissions had to be set.